# Save html instance after update

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this html data-table where each table cell is editable. I can edit the cell value and it is saved temporary. But when I update the page it is lost. So I tried to save the html instance in excel file so that I can see the updated cell in future.

Below function shows me the edited value in console

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  table.MakeCellsEditable({
    "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction

  });

  function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
    console.log("The old value for that cell was: " + oldValue);
    console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
    updatedCell.data();
    updatedRow.data();
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

And This is my Ajax for calling python function:

```
$("#sa").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/save',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      alert('ok')
    }
  })
});
```

And Basically my python function takes a takes the source code of page and save it in excel. But the thing is my table is getting edited but the script is saving the old values. When I it using chromes inspect element I can see the updates value but when I see it using View page source I see the old values.

Can anybody tell how can I take the updated html page source and send it using ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between `page source`and `inspect element` is:

**Page Source** shows what server initially responded, that is the actual sent HTML from the server.

**Inspect Element** is showing the current state of the DOM after JS manipulation.

**DOM** is generated using the entire initial page's source/HTML.

That's why your page source will always be the same.

What you can do is post the html content of `document` in your ajax to get the latest page source.

The following should help you in getting updated DOM source as string:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Though not sure why you need to post source as you can only post updated values and update database accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, But the thing is the table is rendered using pandas form a excel file and I need to save the updates state. Thats why I am sending the page source

Answer (score 0):

Look into [DataTables State saving](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html), it's an option in the plugin [`stateSave: true`] which uses `localstorage` and `sessionStorage` to retain the state of your table.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

Since the state is saved, you can simply retrieve the data everytime you reload the page.